# Splitting a list based on list item contents (string)

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list that contains University lecture times and subjects.

['Week 9 (28/09/15) MA4/PGDE/ BMus','0900-1000 MA4/PGDE Lecture ALT ', '1100-1200 PS Tutorials Groups 1-9 ONLY ','1300-1400 PS Lecture ALT', '1500-1600 PS Lecture ALT ', 'Week 10... and so on...

There are 44 weeks in the altogether, how can I split the list into sub lists using the 'Week' string as the trigger, giving me in sub-lists for each weeks lectures ?  As below

[['Week 9 (28/09/15) MA4/PGDE/ BMus','0900-1000 MA4/PGDE Lecture ALT ', '1100-1200 PS Tutorials Groups 1-9 ONLY ','1300-1400 PS Lecture ALT', '1500-1600 PS Lecture ALT '], ['Week 10... and so on...

I don't have any code ... that's why I'm asking if and how I could do it !

Comment: Please include both a minimal, complete, verifiable example and what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service! Please show what code you have tried and what is not working. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
li=['Week 9 (28/09/15) MA4/PGDE/ BMus','0900-1000 MA4/PGDE Lecture ALT ', '1100-1200 PS Tutorials Groups 1-9 ONLY ','1300-1400 PS Lecture ALT', '1500-1600 PS Lecture ALT ', 'Week 10... ', 'more on 10', 'and more', 'Week 11... ', 'more on 11', 'and more',]
```

You can use `groupby` like so:

```
from itertools import groupby

result=[]
temp=[]
for k, g in groupby(li, key=lambda s: s.lower().startswith('week')):
    if k:
        if temp:
            result.append(temp)
        temp=list(g)
    else:
        temp.extend(list(g))
else:
    result.append(temp)
>>> results
[['Week 9 (28/09/15) MA4/PGDE/ BMus', '0900-1000 MA4/PGDE Lecture ALT ', '1100-1200 PS Tutorials Groups 1-9 ONLY ', '1300-1400 PS Lecture ALT', '1500-1600 PS Lecture ALT '], ['Week 10... ', 'more on 10', 'and more'], ['Week 11... ', 'more on 11', 'and more']]
```

You can also do slices and zip (on the same list) like so:

```
>>> idxs=[i for i, e in enumerate(li) if s.lower().startswith('week')]+[len(li)]
>>> [li[x:y] for x, y in zip(idxs, idxs[1:])]
[['Week 9 (28/09/15) MA4/PGDE/ BMus', '0900-1000 MA4/PGDE Lecture ALT ', '1100-1200 PS Tutorials Groups 1-9 ONLY ', '1300-1400 PS Lecture ALT', '1500-1600 PS Lecture ALT '], ['Week 10... ', 'more on 10', 'and more'], ['Week 11... ', 'more on 11', 'and more']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allWeeks = []
arranged = []

current = []
for i in range(len(allWeeks)):

    if ("Week" in allWeeks[i]): 
        arranged.append(current)
        current = []
        current.append(allWeeks[i])
    elif (i == len(allWeeks) - 1):
        current.append(allWeeks[i])
        arranged.append(current)
    else:
        current.append(allWeeks[i])

for i in arranged:
    print (i)
```

where allWeeks is your starting array and arranged is array, that consists of arrays, starting with element Week.